# depth effect using Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know (as in http://james.padolsey.com/) how the upper body layer is scrolling at a faster speed while the background is scrolled at a slower speed making it give an effect of depth??

Can I implement multiple layers (more then 2) scrolling at different speeds using the similar concept??

Comment: FWIW, this site supports the Konami Code :)

Comment: How?? Where or at which page??

Comment: +1 @Jason: LOL I just went to the site and pressed `up up down down left right left right B A`... hahaha! First time seeing this. This effect is trippy!!

Comment: I went to the homepage, pressed the Konami Code but nothing happened!! :/

Comment: you have to hit enter after you do it for it to work

Comment: i dont know... jst after typing the codes, the browser shows some youtube link loading for a sec and then nothing happens.. probably it's because of my internet speed!! :/

Comment: well, what happens AFTER you hit it isn't a result of the konami code failing. that's just the developer screwing up with his url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the bit of code that does this. I did not write it, just looked at his source and got it.

```
var a = document.body,
    e = document.documentElement;
$(window).unbind("scroll").scroll(function () {
    a.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + -(Math.max(e.scrollTop, a.scrollTop) / 8) + "px"
})
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUB6E/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the code in the source, but I recreated it reasonably:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $('body').css('background-position', 
                  '0 ' + parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*0.5,10) + 'px');
});
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/4JSL9/)

Comment: ninja like reflexes there, not gonna lie... but it does look like the right side is scrolling more than the left or am I mad tripping?